# Отрисовка STEP/STP модели ISO-10303-21

Tags: javafx, 3d, cad

Коллеги, всем доброго дня. Подскажите, шарит кто за формат STEP (он же stp, он же p21, он же ISO 10303)? Пишу на Java программу, которая должна отрисовать stp модель, использую JavaFX 3D для рендеринга. Открываю stp файл и разбираю его регулярными выражениями. Я так понимаю "CARTESIAN_POINT" - это некие вершины и их можно как-то связать в полигоны или что то вроде того, но я пока не понимаю как. Может кто объяснить как строятся модели из файлов stp?